# error in the quick sort code but not displaying in the error window

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort

[image: sorting - quick sort]

I have an error in the quick sort code. There is a problem in output. The output window comes up and the program crashes.

It is not even showing an error. Where is the error in the code?

Comment: No code images please! Post the code in the question. And please describe sample input, expected output and what you have done to debug the problem. If a program doesn't work at first, a developer's job is to debug it (and no, posting immediately on Stackoverflow is not counted as debugging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `partition` function returns `pindex` which is equal to `a[end]` and not the index of the partition point. That will cause an out-of-range access in the recursive call of the `sort` function.